# How do I restart a docker container which exited prematurely with exitCode 127?

Tags: docker

My docker container exited prematurely when my computer blacked out and now it can't restart anymore.

When I attempt to start it, I get the following error:

Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:424: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\"/tmp/.docker.xauth\\" to rootfs \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dc93a6129b9d45cd1e79da2cf2f634b5bd09ae4ec5e36d1a0b1518b69badbebc/merged\\" at \\"/var/lib/docker/overlay2/dc93a6129b9d45cd1e79da2cf2f634b5bd09ae4ec5e36d1a0b1518b69badbebc/merged/tmp/.docker.xauth\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type
Error: failed to start containers: xxxx

Comment: If your computer crashed, the host system's `/tmp` might have gotten wiped out.  I'd `docker rm` the container and re-run whatever sequence started it initially.

Comment: I assume that you want to mount your localhost file `/tmp/.docker.xauth` to container file `/tmp/.docker.xauth`. Besides restarting container you could check following:
1. Is `/tmp/.docker.xauth` existing on localhost as file (not directory)
2. have you mounted any other folder to container folder `/tmp` before and `.docker.xauth` does exist in there as a folder?
Otherwise I would suggest to rebuild the image of the container